# Don't understand why PHP string written this way?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$_REQUEST['one']='John';
$_REQUEST['two']='Habernash';

$output= "  insert into tbl_user set first_name=' " .$_REQUEST['one']. " ',
last_name=' " .$_REQUEST['two']. " '   ";
```

I don't understand what is going on here with the strings. I read that the outermost quotes determine whether the inside variables will be evaluated or not. So why are the concatenation operators and double quotes needed surrounding the request variables? I tried another piece of code and instead of doing ' ". $_REQUEST['one'] ." ' I did ' { $_REQUEST['one'] } ' and it produced the same output. So is there a reason why the ". ." method is better and how does it work exactly? Just confused, thanks for the help.

Comment: Learn basic PHP syntax: https://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: I edited your question to show syntax highlighting. Look closely, that should help.

Comment: The *"double quotes needed surrounding the request variables"* are **not** that. They close the string literals before and after the variable evaluations. Those "strings" embed a `'` which will be printed to surround the variable that is printed.   `insert into tbl_user set first_name=' John ', last_name=' Habernash '`

Comment: Ohhh, thanks castis that actually makes more sense! I get it now, I was using notepad++ so the syntax highlighting wasn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is how some database SQL is written. If the column expects a string, it expects the variable to be wrapped in quotes -- thus the single quotes around the escaping double doubles.

Double quotes here: PHP string. Single quotes: SQL string.

Note here that this code you have is practicing poor habits of not sanitizing SQL strings by allowing raw input directly into the SQL string.